# zsh I/O redirection: redirecting and then piping; what is going on?

Tags: zsh, pipe, io-redirection

Can somebody explain what is going on in this command:

```
echo foo >&2 | grep foo
```

Zsh (5.0.2) prints `foo` twice. One seemingly to stdout and one to stderr, since running these commands:

```
{ echo foo >&2 | grep foo } >/dev/null
```

and:

```
{ echo foo >&2 | grep foo } 2>/dev/null
```

both just print `foo` once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the effect of [MULTIOS](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios).

```
echo foo >&2 | grep foo
```

will write `foo` to stderr and also pipe `foo` to `grep`. Because stderr defaults to terminal, you will see two `foo` lines, one from `echo`, one from the `grep` result.

```
{ echo foo >&2 | grep foo } >/dev/null
```

Here, you saw one line because stdout was redirected to `/dev/null`, you only saw the `foo` line from `echo`.

```
{ echo foo >&2 | grep foo } 2>/dev/null
```

Here, you saw one line because stderr was redirected to `/dev/null`, you only saw the `foo` line from `grep`.

You can easily see the difference in the terminal by the line output color. `grep` will highlight the matched pattern (or you can force it to by using `--color=always`).

---

`MULTIOS` was enabled by default with `nomultios` option unset:

```
$ unsetopt | grep nomultios
nomultios
```

To disable it, just set `nomultios` option:

```
$ setopt nomultios
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know zsh could do that! I (basically) understand redirection, I wanted to know why the command wasn't equivalent to `{echo  foo >&2} | grep foo`, if you see what I'm trying to say. I thought the command I asked about above would have redirected stdout to stderr and then piped empty stdout to grep.

Comment: @Zorawar: That question was not addressed in your post, so I will answer here. In `{echo foo >&2} | grep foo`, `{echo foo >&2}` was considered as a command, and it ran in a subshell. You can think it like `A | grep foo` where `A` is `{echo foo >&2}`. In this case, `>&2` and `|` were separated, `MULTIOS` has no effect here.

Comment: @Zorawar This case is why I ended up turning off multios. It's a cute idea, but in practice I found it often annoying and rarely useful.

Comment: @cuonglm, I have another question that is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53985239/7026980) but didn't get any answer. If you know it and also have time, could you please help?