# pipe reads from stdin even when stdout of previous command is routed to dev null

Tags: shell, zsh, pipe, io-redirection

I was playing around with my shell (`zsh v4.3.11`) when I noticed something weird:

```
$ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null echo "Hello"
```

outputs nothing on the terminal, whereas

```
$ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null echo "Hello" | wc
```

outputs:

```
1 1 6
```

How does the redirection/pipe combination work here? How does `wc` see the `Hello\n` even though all output is redirected to `/dev/null`? And why do I see the output of `wc` when I've redirected everything to `/dev/null`?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with zsh to be sure, but it may be a duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212920/117549

Comment: particularly the ["MULTIOS" bit](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html)

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335585/117549

Comment: Thank you, everyone - I was unable to find a related question on searching and wasn't helped by the fact that my question changed halfway through framing rendering my prior search a little unrelated. Apologies!